# How to use git repository for IntelliJ Code Style

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ide

We have our code style settings in a private git repository. I want to use this git URL to set my project's code style.

Right now, I clone this repository and import the XML into IntelliJ. The issue is as the repository is updated, I need to manually `git pull` on my local computer.

I know there is https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/sharing-your-ide-settings.html but that shares your entire setting - I just want code style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Read-only sources in Settings Repository. You could create a separate repo and put code style there, and add it as a read-only source.